# Force return error in golang

Tags: go

I want to test how certain code handles errors.

I want a function to return an error.

I have tried typing `return 0/0` but then my application won't build

How can I force return an error?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can return errors like this:

```
func ReturnError() (string, error){       
      return "", fmt.Errorf("this is an %s error", "internal server")
      // or
      return "", errors.New("this is an error")
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) I thought we had to write a custom Error function everytime we need to return an error.
https://tour.golang.org/methods/19

Comment: Why do you explicitly return an empty string, first?

Comment: You don't have to. Its just an example. You can return just the error if that suits your use case more.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `errors` package.

```
import "errors"

// [ ... ]

func failFunc() error {
    return errors.New("Error message")
}
```

Here's the godoc: https://godoc.org/errors